# What mean ERROR message in JBoss 7.1, Seam Web Project

Tags: jboss

I try to deploy Seam Web Project and I have dwo errors:

> 135 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015010: The deployment scanner found a directory named META-INF that was not inside a directory whose name ends with .ear, .jar, .rar, .sar or .war. This is likely the result of unzipping an archive directly inside the D:\Karolina\programy\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments directory, which is a user error. The META-INF directory will not be scanned for deployments, but it is possible that the scanner mayfind other files from the unzipped archive and attempt to deploy them, leading to errors.

> 135 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015010: The deployment scanner found a directory named WEB-INF that was not inside a directory whose name ends with .ear, .jar, .rar, .sar or .war. This is likely the result of unzipping an archive directly inside the D:\Karolina\programy\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments directory, which is a user error. The WEB-INF directory will not be scanned for deployments, but it is possible that the scanner mayfind other files from the unzipped archive and attempt to deploy them, leading to errors.

Enyone know what it mean and what should I do to fix it?
I will glad for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that you are most likely trying to deploy a so called *exploded* archive, but exploded archive support has changed in JBossAS7.

Java EE 6 has made many xml deployment descriptors optional, which was a big win for devs, but app-server like JBoss had to change their way of identifying archive types, because now they can't rely on checking files/dirs for presence of xml descriptors.

You can find more details in [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Application+deployment).